# iOS Facebook Account kit - Persist user token when app is opened 2nd time after successful login

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, account-kit

My doubt is after successful login using Facebook account kit for the first time, I am reopening the app for the 2nd time. When I open how can I detect and use the existing user Access Token?

I tried by fetching Accountkit.currentAccessToken in appdelegate as a condition to show login page or welcome page. But currentAccessToken returns me null. 
I have also enabled **"Enable Client Access Token Flow"** in app settings. 
Kindly help to understand if my approach is right.

```
 self.accountKit = AKFAccountKit (responseType: AKFResponseType.accessToken)
        if(self.accountKit.currentAccessToken != nil)
        {
            //SHOW WELCOME PAGE
        }else{
            //SHOW LOGIN PAGE
        }
```

Comment: Can you paste in your code that starts the Account Kit flow? Did you set it up to use the Token response type?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Below is the code used:

`var accountKit = AKFAccountKit (responseType: AKFResponseType.accessToken)

 self.accountKit.accountPreferences()?.delegate = self

 let loginViewController:AKFViewController = accountKit.viewControllerForPhoneLogin(with: nil, state: inputString) as! AKFViewController
 loginViewController.defaultCountryCode = "IN"
 loginViewController.enableSendToFacebook = true`

Comment: @OlgaKuznetsova can you help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am facing the same issue in Android (not in iOS) but I think the problem is same, since in the document says it so.

this is my code for configuring the login using Email (kotlin, use `let` to change the `val`).

```
val configurationBuilder = AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder(
            LoginType.EMAIL,
            AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.CODE)
```

notice that the response type is `AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.CODE`

In the document says:

> If you began the login session with `AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.TOKEN`, a logout option is available to remove the stored AccessToken from the device.

So the problem is on the Response type that I use, need to be changed into `AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.TOKEN` in order to make the token stored on devices.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen some issues with Xcode8 / iOS 10 Simulators and keychain save/retrieval. See https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/60617

AccountKit stores the accessToken securely in the keychain but there is an intermittent bug on Xcode8 / iOS 10 Simulators that makes read/write from keychain fail.

Can you test if this is also happening on a Device? 
Apparently the problem goes away if you add the Shared Keychain Entitlement to your App, but this is still a bug on Apple.